# Displaying HTML entities in title through a view

Tags: 7, views

I have a site (D7) where I need to have HTML entities in the title like the copyright, trade mark signs with the subscript tags. Like:

**Product name<sup>®</sup>**

The solution at the node level is simple using the page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print html_entity_decode($title); ?>
```

But in a view no matter how I try to format the title it will always return it like

```
Product name<sup>&reg;</sup>
```

I try a formatter, but they don't reach the title. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem, no solution yet.

Comment: Do you enter the title with html-entities or as unicode characters?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You need to add the attribute `'html' => true`. This is a link property in Drupal 7. If you render any link in Drupal 7 and want to add some extra HTML inside it you need to set `array('html'=>true)`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using templates:
In case of a view page, the template used will be page--.tpl.php. Ex: If the path to the page is awards then the page template file is page--awards.tpl.php. The title can be edited as required in the template file.

In case of a block, the title can be edited using the block.tpl.php. [Refer to this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) for creating the template file for a specific block. Here are the other references for this topic.

https://www.drupal.org/node/270332

https://www.drupal.org/node/792590

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it, but I think my method is not perfect.
I created another filed, called "title2", text field with "Full HTML". Make Title2 = title, and view it in views, it will be html_entity_decoded.
Sorry for my n00b english.

Comment: I can see your point, but I think that is a little bit overkilling. Thank you and happy new year!